# HBase: How can you determine if your call to delete actually deleted a row?

Tags: hbase, delete-row

In HBase 1.x, there's a delete method on a Table object that allows you to delete an entire row.  However, it "succeeds" whether that row is actually in the table or not (there's no return value).  Is there a way to determine if a row has been deleted by a particular call to Table.delete in HBase?

I imagine that checkAndDelete might be appropriate for this, e.g., checking if the row is present first.  Something like this:

```
boolean deleted = false;
try (Table table = getTable(TABLE_NAME)) {
  byte[] rowKey = Bytes.toBytes(rowId);
  deleted = table.checkAndDelete(???, new Delete(rowKey));
} catch (Exception e) {
  // handle exceptions here
}
// here I know if the row was deleted or not
```

I'm not sure what condition to put in the '???' part.  I've tried checking to see that a column value (which I know is present) is not empty, but that didn't work.  In order to achieve the same effect, I've had to replace the checkAndDelete with two calls instead (exists, then delete):

```
  if (table.exists(new Get(rowKey))) {
    table.delete(new Delete(rowKey));
    deleted = true;  // row deleted
  }
```

One atomic call would be much nicer.  Surely someone else has done something similar to this.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to determine if a row has been deleted by a particular
>   call to Table.delete in HBase?

We use a higher level SQL layer at Splice Machine (Open Source) but if you think of what a delete is it is a scan and then a delete (batch puts for logical delete and batch deletes for physical deletes).

The checkAndPut explanation is below...

```
/**
   * Atomically checks if a row/family/qualifier value matches the expected
   * value. If it does, it adds the put.  If the passed value is null, the check
   * is for the lack of column (ie: non-existance)
   *
   * @param row to check
   * @param family column family to check
   * @param qualifier column qualifier to check
   * @param value the expected value
   * @param put data to put if check succeeds
   * @throws IOException e
   * @return true if the new put was executed, false otherwise
   */
```

You could always crank out a coprocessor call to override the existing functionality.  You could do it as an Observer or an Endpoint.

Comment: Hmmm... if it is implemented as a scan then a delete, then why doesn't it throw an exception when the row isn't there, since the scan result would be empty?  

We use checkAndPut other places, that's what inspired the idea of using checkAndDelete.  When I tried checking for the non-existence of a column that I knew wasn't there, it failed the check (not sure why... the column wasn't there).  I didn't try adding a dummy column and checking its value (that seems like a very hacky solution).  

I'm surprised that this use case (knowing if the delete actually did work or not) is so uncommon.